# Entity error id is null, even when it's autogenerated

Tags: spring

I'm working with Spring Boot and I have an error I don't understand. My entities ids are annotated with @GeneratedValue and @NotNull but when I fill de form the Controller Validator fails and says " Id is null". I though id should be automatically generated. I've written on purpose @NotNull because this error used to appear in the service.
Alumno is Student, Legajo is the "file" where his data is recorded along the years he stays in the school and every year some data changes. Curso is the level in the school where the student is. TrayectoriaAcademica is a collection of those levels,  untill the student graduates.
¿ How can I make to automatically generate Entities ids?

This is my Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="alumno")
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor 
public class Alumno {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    @NotNull(message="El id del Alumno es Nulo :S, Id is null")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column
    @Length(max=25)
    @NotEmpty(message="Debe escribir su apellido")
    @Size(max=25,message="El apellido debe contener como máximo 25 caracteres") 
    private String apellido;
    
    @Column
    @Length(max=25)
    @Size(max=25,message="El nombre debe contener como máximo 25 caracteres y como mínimo 2")
    @NotEmpty(message="Debe escribir su nombre")
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column
    @Length(max=15)
    @NotEmpty(message="Debe escribir su fecha de nacimiento")
    private String fechaNacimiento;
    
    @Column(length=8)
    @Size(max=8,min=8,message="El dni debe tener 8 digitos sin puntos ")
    @NotEmpty(message="Debe escribir su dni")
    @Pattern(regexp="\\d+",message="Debe escribir en su dni solo los 8 números del mismo, sin puntos")// Esto \\d es digitos y el + q se puede repetir una o mas veces
    private String dni;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="alumno")
    private Legajo legajo;

    
    

}
```

This is my form

```
<form th:object="${alumno}" th:action="@{/admin/inscripciones}" action="#"method="post">
            
                <input id="id" th:field="*{id}"type="hidden"> 
                
                <div class="form-row justify-content-around">
                    <div class="form-group col-6">
                        <label for="apellido">Apellido</label> 
                        <input id="apellido"type="text" th:field="*{apellido}"class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-6">
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                         <input id="nombre"type="text" th:field="*{nombre}"class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-3">
                        <label for="nacimiento">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                         <input id="nacimiento"  th:field="*{fechaNacimiento}"type="date" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-3">
                        <label >Documento</label> 
                        <input id="dni"type="text"th:field="*{dni}"class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class=" mt-3 form-check-inline">
                        <label class="form-check-label"for="reinscripto">
                        <input class="form-check-input"id="reinscripto"type="checkbox">
                        Reinscripto</label> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-3">
                        <label for="fechaInscripcion">Fecha de Inscripción</label>
                         <input id="fechaInscripcion"th:field="${trayectoria.idTya.fechaInscripcion}"type="date" value="2020-06-06" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-around">
                        
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label for="curso">Curso</label>
                                     <select id="curso"class="form-control" th:field="${curso.nombreCurso}">
                                        <option th:value=" '1º' " th:text=" '1º' "></option>
                                        <option th:value=" '2º' " th:text=" '2º' "></option>
                                        <option th:value=" '3º' " th:text=" '3º' "></option>
                                        <option th:value=" '4º' " th:text=" '4º' "></option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label for="division">Division</label> 
                                    <select id="division" class="form-control"th:field="${curso.division}">
                                        <option th:value=" '1º' " th:text=" '1º' "></option>
                                        <option th:value=" '2º' " th:text=" '2º' "></option>
                                        <option th:value=" '3º' " th:text=" '3º' "></option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-3">
                                    <label for="ciclo">Ciclo </label> 
                                    <select id="ciclo"class="form-control"th:field="${curso.ciclo}">
                                        <option th:value="Básico" th:text="Básico"></option>
                                        <option th:value="Superior" th:text="Superior"></option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-3">
                                    <label for="turno">Turno</label>
                                     <select id="turno"class="form-control"th:field="${curso.turno}">
                                        <option th:value="'M'" th:text="Mañana"></option>
                                        <option th:value="'T'" th:text="Tarde"></option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-4">
                                    <label for="condicion">Condición</label>
                                     <select id="condicion"class="form-control"th:field="${trayectoria.condicion}">
                                        <option th:value="Regular" th:text="Regular"></option>
                                        <option th:value="Repitente" th:text="Repitente"></option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div id="pendientes" class="form-group col-4">
                                    
                                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">                       
                                <input class="btn col-3 btn-primary"type="submit" value="enviar">                           
                    </div>

                    <ul th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}">
                        <li class="text-danger text-center" th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" th:text="${err}">Input is incorrect</li>
                    </ul>
            </form>
```

This is the code in Controller that manages de form

```
@GetMapping("/inscripciones")
    public ModelAndView showForm() {
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("titulo","Usuario Administrativo");
        mav.setViewName("form");
        mav.addObject("alumno",new Alumno());
        mav.addObject("trayectoria",new TrayectoriaAcademica());
        mav.addObject("curso",new Curso());
        return mav;
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/inscripciones")
    public String  inscribir( @ModelAttribute("alumno") @Valid Alumno alumno,BindingResult alumnoValid,
             @Valid @ModelAttribute("curso") Curso curso,BindingResult cursoValid,@Valid @ModelAttribute("trayectoria") TrayectoriaAcademica trayectoria,
             BindingResult trayValid,@ModelAttribute("legajo") Legajo legajo) throws Exception {
        
        if(alumnoValid.hasErrors()||cursoValid.hasErrors()||trayValid.hasErrors()) {
            return "form";
        }
        if(legajo==null) {
            servicio.inscribirAlumno(alumno, trayectoria, curso);
            return "redirect:/admin/inscripciones";
        }else {
            servicio.reinscribirAlumno(legajo, trayectoria);
            return "redirect:/admin/inscripciones";
        }

    }
```

Data don't reach this point, but in case it helps to understand..

```
@Override
    @Transactional //This method creates a new object for it's arguments. curso is in a select, it's filled in DataBase at the begining.
    public void inscribirAlumno(Alumno al, TrayectoriaAcademica tya, Curso curso) throws Exception {
            
        Legajo legajo=new Legajo();
        al.setLegajo(legajo);
        legajo.setIdLegajo(al.getId());         
        aluRep.save(al);
        tya.setCurso(cursoRep.findBynombreCursoAndDivisionAndCicloAndTurno(curso.getNombreCurso(), curso.getDivision(),
                    curso.getCiclo(), curso.getTurno()));
        legajo.getInscripciones().add(tya);                 
        trayectoriaRep.save(tya);               
        legajoRep.save(legajo);

    }

    @Override
    public Alumno findAlumnoById(Integer id) {
        Optional<Alumno> alumno=aluRep.findById(id);
        return alumno.get();
    }

    @Override
    public Legajo findLegajoById(Integer id) {
        Optional<Legajo> legajo=legajoRep.findById(id);
        return legajo.get();
    }

    @Override // This method changes only Legajo object because the others already exist.
    public void reinscribirAlumno(Legajo legajo, TrayectoriaAcademica tya) {
        legajo.getInscripciones().add(tya);
        trayectoriaRep.save(tya);
        legajoRep.save(legajo);
        
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Validation annotation is needed only for fields you enter manually. Since you are not entering `id` field you don't need to validate it. So you should remove `NotNull` annotation from `id` field.

Comment: I've annotated it on purpose to make me easy to see the error. The first time I saw it it was in the service Implementation the id attribute reached that point being null. My problem is why it doent generate its id by itself.

Comment: Because `@GeneratedValue` shows that id value will be generated by underlying database (like MySQL) AFTER you save the new entity, not before. It shouldn't be generated by application. It's completely ok when entity reaches save operation with id null.